# improve if condition with scala

Tags: scala

I wrote this:

```
if (fork == "0" || fork == "1" || fork == "3" || fork == "null"  ) {
 list2 :: List(
    Wrapper(
      Location.PL_TYPES,
      subType,
      daFuncId,
      NA,
      name,
      code)
  )
}
else list2  :: List(
  Wrapper(
    Location.PL_TYPES,
    subType,
    NA,
    NA,
    name,
    code
  )
)

}
```

I want to improve this by replacing the if else with another pattern

best regards

Comment: You can use pattern matching of scala

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems only the ID is different between the two cases. You could use pattern matching to choose the id, and append to the list only after so you don't repeat the `Wrapper` construction:

```
val id = fork match {
  case "0" | "1" | "3" | "null" => daFuncId
  case _ => NA
}

list2 :: List(
  Wrapper(
    Location.PL_TYPES,
    subType,
    id,
    NA,
    name,
    code)
)
```

Comment: `val id = if (Set("0","1","3","null")(fork)) daFuncId else NA` as an alternative. Still `if` pattern, but a bit shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the same if-else condition using pattern matching in scala.

```
fork match {
  case "0" | "1" | "3" | null =>
    list2 :: List(
      Wrapper(
        Location.PL_TYPES,
        subType,
        daFuncId,
        NA,
        name,
        code)
    )
  case _ =>
    list2  :: List(
      Wrapper(
        Location.PL_TYPES,
        subType,
        NA,
        NA,
        name,
        code
      )
    )
}
```

Please let me know if this works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 list2 :: List(fork)
  .map {
     case "0" | "1" | "3" | "null" => daFuncId
     case _ => NA
  }.map { id => 
    Wrapper(Location.PL_TYPES, subType, id, NA, name, code)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really scala specific but I'd suggest something like this:

```
if (List("0", "1", "3", "null").contains(fork)) {

} else {

}
```